# Finding skewness and kurtosis numerically in Mathematica

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a function given by

```
f[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] = ProbabilityDistribution[a b c k x^(c - 1) 
(1 + x^c)^(k - 1) ((1 + x^c)^k - 1)^(-b - 1) (1 + g ((1 + x^c)^k -1)
^-b)^(-(a/g) - 1), {x, 0, inf}, 
Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && g > 0 && c > 0 && k > 0]
```

I want to find skewness for certain values of a,b,g,c,k.

How to find the skewness and kurtosis numerically in Mathematica?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with a corrected version of your `ProbabilityDistribution`

```
f[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[
  a b c k x^(c - 1) (1 + x^c)^(k - 1) ((1 + x^c)^k - 1)^(-b - 1) (1 + 
      g ((1 + x^c)^k - 1)^-b)^(-(a/g) - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && g > 0 && c > 0 && k > 0]
```

One can define the numerical mean value as

```
mu[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] := 
 NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] f[a, b, g, c, k]]
```

the numerical skewness as

```
skewness[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] := 
 NExpectation[((x - mu[a, b, g, c, k])/Sqrt@NExpectation[(x - mu[a, b, g, c, k])^2, 
  x \[Distributed] f[a, b, g, c, k]])^3, x \[Distributed] f[a, b, g, c, k]]
```

and the numerical kurtosis as

```
kurtosis[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] := 
 NExpectation[(x - mu[a, b, g, c, k])^4, x \[Distributed] f[a, b, g, c, k]]/
 NExpectation[(x - mu[a, b, g, c, k])^2, x \[Distributed] f[a, b, g, c, k]]^2
```

Testing with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` as the "certain values of a,b,g,c,k"

```
mu[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
skewness[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
kurtosis[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> `0.551698`
>   `-0.397584`
>   `2.94902`

and comparing with a plot of the `PDF`

```
Plot[PDF[f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]][x], {x, -0.3, 1.75}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: PDF]

Using central moments as suggested in [the comment by Guess who it is.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87290/finding-skewness-and-kurtosis-numerically-in-mathematica/87310?noredirect=1#comment237557_87310)

```
zm[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_][m_] := 
 NExpectation[(x - mu[a, b, g, c, k])^m, x \[Distributed] f[a, b, g, c, k]]
```

Now the skewness can be defined as

```
mSkewness[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] := 
 zm[a, b, g, c, k][3]/(zm[a, b, g, c, k][2])^(3/2)

mSkewness[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> `-0.397584`

and the kurtosis as

```
mKurtosis[a_, b_, g_, c_, k_] := 
 zm[a, b, g, c, k][4]/(zm[a, b, g, c, k][2])^2

mKurtosis[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

> `2.94902`

Comment: Another possibility would be to just define a function for the moments, and then assemble the expressions for variance, skewness, and kurtosis in terms of those moments. Tho, this may or may not be more numerically stable, so some testing would be needed.

Comment: One could also use the definitions based on the cumulants.

Comment: @wolfies Thank you for the clarifying and explanatory comment to my earlier answer.

Comment: @Karsten7.thanks a lot both solutions are working just fine.