# Statistical parameters from distribution function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a number of distributions that I am adding to result in one summarized distribution, e.g.:

```
distSum={0.167467 E^(-(1/2) (-21.5 + x)^2), 0.160772 E^(-(1/2) (-19.7 + x)^2),
  0.233762 E^(-(1/2) (-21.7 + x)^2), 
 0.0930353 E^(-(1/2) (-21.9 + x)^2), 
 0.373293 E^(-(1/2) (-22.4 + x)^2), 0.126876 E^(-(1/2) (-19. + x)^2), 
 0.348056 E^(-(1/2) (-22.7 + x)^2), 0.393082 E^(-(1/2) (-21.4 + x)^2),
  0.35867 E^(-(1/2) (-20.9 + x)^2), 0.383496 E^(-(1/2) (-22.3 + x)^2)}
```

Now I would like to have some information and lists from the single `distSum`. E.g., what is the Mean/Median/etc of `distSum`? Also, I'd like to extract a sample from `distSum`, but I can't simply use `RandomSample` on `distSum`. I know how to apply these statistical parameters on lists, but as this is a function, and not a list, I don't know how to get these parameters.

[image]

Comment: ...so a bunch of Gaussians?

Comment: In this case yes, but is just an example. Could also be others.

Comment: @Karsten7. No – but I just tried NExpectation, as I think that's what you were referring to. No result. If I could get a list from distSum, then I could basically apply what I need. But I don't know, how to transfer this distribution function in a list that would basically produce the same histogram as the function.

Comment: None of these functions are probability distributions as none of them integrate to 1 and the integral of the sum isn't 1 either.  So why do you call them distributions?

Comment: @JimBaldwin That's probably just because of the scaling factor in front of each function. This is to weight the impact of each distribution the summed distribution.

Comment: I understand you want a weighted average of the functions.  My objection is calling the functions distributions and somehow letting some other process down the road take care of the weighting so that things integrate to one.  Seems to me to be a loose end that could possibly cause trouble.  I'm suggesting that you should take care of the weighting and the "integration to 1" for all of the distributions separately and explicitly.

Comment: What does it even mean to say: "I have a number of distributions that I am adding"

Comment: @JimBaldwin &wolfies Yes, I'm not a statistician and thankful for the answers I get here. I know there are many, as you, who could have phrased it more precise.

Comment: Rather than asking for more precise statistical terms, I'd say we're really asking for more or clarifying information so that we can understand the question better and provide you with an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `MixtureDistribution` thus

```
Integrate[distSum, {x, -∞, ∞}] // Chop
Integrate[x distSum, {x, -∞, ∞}] // Chop
means = %/%%
weights = %%%/Total[%%%]
dist = MixtureDistribution[weights, NormalDistribution[#, 1] & /@ means]
```

and apply most of the statistical functions to it

```
Through[{Mean, Variance, Median, RandomReal}[dist]]
(* {21.6074, 1.94362, 21.7081, 21.8625} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can apply the same principles used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87310/18476) to your problem:

```
distSum = {0.167467 E^(-(1/2) (-21.5 + x)^2), 0.160772 E^(-(1/2) (-19.7 + x)^2), 
   0.233762 E^(-(1/2) (-21.7 + x)^2), 0.0930353 E^(-(1/2) (-21.9 + x)^2), 
   0.373293 E^(-(1/2) (-22.4 + x)^2), 0.126876 E^(-(1/2) (-19. + x)^2), 
   0.348056 E^(-(1/2) (-22.7 + x)^2), 0.393082 E^(-(1/2) (-21.4 + x)^2), 
   0.35867 E^(-(1/2) (-20.9 + x)^2), 0.383496 E^(-(1/2) (-22.3 + x)^2)};

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
        Plus @@ distSum, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "Normalize"];

mean = NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] dist]
```

$\ $ `21.6074`

```
variance = Expectation[(x - mean)^2, x \[Distributed] dist] // Chop
```

$\ $ `1.94362`

```
Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 12, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Out]

```
RandomVariate[dist, 10]
```

$\ $ `{20.7231, 21.2831, 20.6987, 22.486, 22.7043, 25.5388, 21.5406, 21.9175, 20.5078, 21.9182}`

Comment: I see, thanks, Karsten.